# Better Method to call image from server (Creating Cdn)

Tags: php, html, cdn, pagespeed

Hi we are creating a website . In which we have to display so many images . So we upload the the images in the same website and called . For eg : `<img src="mysite.com/img/tes1.jpg" >` .

Now we are thinking that , instead of calling image from the same website , we can call the image from different website . For this we buy a domain and upload all the images and  call the image to `mysite.com` using `<img src="example.com/img/test1.jpg">` .

Please any one tell this is good method or bad ?

In which method i get minimum loading time and less page size?

> Edit : The better method is using the **cdn** . That i know . But actually
>   cdn for to  put the content as close to the end-user as possible. Think if
>   my location is UAE(Dubai) , even i used the cdn still the nearest
>   location of the cdn server  distributed  is in Hongcong or somewhere in Asia  that not near to our location.
>
> I checked with some cdn providers . Still the nearest location is so far
>   from our current country location in which we want to show our website
>   fast . What we can do in that point ?

Also How  **Facebook** and **YouTube** are loading images and video fast ?

If anyone have good idea please help .

Comment: The best option is Image Optimization, reduce size of image(s), and then no need to use other server or CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload your images on a secondary website but it does seem like an intricate solution given the probable scope of your problem. You could instead use a CDN service (like Amazon) which probably gives you better loading times and also makes the server less cluttered with requests, which also speeds it up.